# Linked In Api to get Linked in Profiles

Tags: java, php, javascript

I have a  list of first name, last name, email address, city, state and employer. I want to collect all of these individual's Linkedin profiles.Please Help ,Which API can be used and is there any demo example.

Thanks,
Sharma

Answer (score 1):

The People Search API looks like your best bet: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

You can find a decent PHP demo here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-people-search